# Firebase query by value in nested nodes

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my document:

[image]

Let's say I have access to the following keys and values: `29 August 2018`, `14:00 - 15:00` and `vyMDLD3V6paRWiA7Xlp12zanT7h1`. How can I combine those in query so that I get the parent key `-LKVpa_1QviUn1RFlEPr`?

I tried several versions:

1. queryByValue, where value is equal to the `id`.
2. queryByKey, where key is equal to `29 August 2018`
3. queryByChild, where child is equal to `29 August 2018`

I got zero results or the entire document.

**The end goal is to delete these nodes**, so if you know any other method to do this (besides searching the database for the parent IDs then deleting), I would appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "29 August 2018/14:00 - 15:00")
   .queryEqual(toValue: "vyMDLD3V6paRWiA7Xlp12zanT7h1")
```

With `ref` pointing to `bookedCourtsDaily`. This will work, but for efficient execution it requires that you define an index on each timeslot. So in your rules you'll need something like:

```
{  
  "bookedCourtsDaily": {
    "$date": { 
      ".indexOn": ["13:00 - 14:00", "14:00 - 15:00", "15:00 - 16:00"] // etc
    }
  }
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, I'd recommend the more common approach of creating an inverse lookup in your JSON:

```
{
  "codeToAppointment": {
    "vyMDLD3V6paRWiA7Xlp12zanT7h1": "29 August 2018/14:00 - 15:00",
    "anotherCode": "28 August 2018/11:00 - 12:00"
  }
}
```

With this structure you can look up the path to an appointment from the "code" (or whatever else the meaning of the value in the JSON is).

Data duplication like this is quite common in NoSQL databases like Firebase.

Comment: Thank you! A very comprehensive answer from which I learned new stuff. Inverse lookup table it will be, because I don't know the slots in advance.

Comment: Is it better to save values as `29 August 2018/14:00 - 15:00` or create two child nodes `day: 29 August 2018` and `hours: 14:00 - 15:00`. Of course, each case can be easily handled by my frontend; but I want to anticipate potential future problems.

Comment: I usually show a single value, since I tend to use them as a path. `ref.child("bookedCourtsDaily").child(snapshot.val())`. But if there's a chance you need the separate values, storing two properties will be better, because you won't have to parse the string.